# App crashing due to multiple user account or work profile in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

> Instant Run detected that you are running on a target device that has
>   a work profile or multiple user accounts. Launching the app under a
>   work profile or another user account on the target device will result
>   in a crash. Learn more about how to run your app under a work profile.

This is the error showing on my event log.
What should I do to run my app on my device? Is there any solution??

Comment: possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44341690/4244598

Comment: Instant run seems like it still has a lot of bugs to me.  I'd consider just turning it off.

Comment: i am not getting the exact solution how to fix. can anybody explain . as i am new to android